# How to change parent category for an existing child category?

Tags: magento2, category

I have a child category and its parent category. How can I change parent category for this child category? Programatically, in a module helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say `$category` is your child category. And you want to make it a child of the category `$parentCategory`.

You can call this:

```
$category->move($parentCategory->getId(), null);
```

Comment: ? you've got to be kidding me! :) I will try, but I am open to other suggestions :)

Comment: why do you think I'm kidding? There is the `move` method: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category.php#L378

Comment: will it properly move its products too, is my only concern...

Comment: the products associated to the child category remain associated to that category. But you might need to reindex though.

Comment: I am missing the second argument for the method ->move($parent, $afterChild). Do you know how can I get last child of the parent category?

Comment: Further more, what if the parent category doesn't have any children? What would come as the second category? I know I am expanding this question, but I need to do this.

Comment: Solved. I didn't see your answer properly. Second argument can be simply null. Thank you very much!